# How to Reduce Physical memory increase in Matlab?

Tags: java, class, matlab, object, memory-leaks

When running the following code in Matlab, the physical memory usage of Matlab increases until it reaches 90% of my system memory, and crashes the program. This code is part of a larger optimization scheme that will have many more iterations, but it has been simplified here.

```
import org.parent.modeling.*

for i = 1:100
    rTool = Tool('C:/etc');
    model = rTool.getModel();
    model.initSystem();
    rTool.setModel(model);
    rTool.run();
end
```

`rTool` and model are stored as Java objects in the workspace. 
By selectively removing steps from the bottom to top, I've determined that the `rTool.run()`; step is causing an incremental memory increase during each iteration. 
I've tried using a variety of memory clearing techniques with no success

```
clear classes, clear java, clear rTool model, clear all
```

I have checked for fragmentation by running the `memory` command, but it is insignificant.
Below is the actual code that corresponds to the API documentation (https://simtk.org/api_docs/opensim/api_docs/classOpenSim_1_1RRATool.html)

```
for i = 1:1:4

    import org.opensim.modeling.*

    rraTool = RRATool('C:\...filename.xml');
    model = rraTool.getModel();
    model.initSystem();

    rraTool.setModel(model);
    rraTool.run();

end
```

Any suggestions for reducing the physical memory increase?

Matlab: 2013

Comment: Where are the API docs for `Tool`?  Or `org.parent.modeling.*`?

Comment: https://simtk.org/api_docs/opensim/api_docs/classOpenSim_1_1RRATool.html

The original code was generic. I added the actual code above.

Comment: The API docs you linked to are C++ not Java.  Why did you tag this with Java?

Comment: I'm new to this. They are Java objects in Matlab.

Comment: So why did you send me C++ API docs.  Aren't there any Java docs?  The problem is that Java and C++ have different ways of doing memory management.  If you don't work from the Java documentation you are liable to do something that causes a C++ memory leak (assuming that you are calling a C++ native library via Java)

Comment: Like you mentioned, Matlab is able to access the C++ code through the Java wrapper. I'm not aware of any Java docs, other than the generic ones. I was hoping that there were some general memory clearing Java commands I could use.

Comment: Related http://askubuntu.com/q/799834/25388

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to figure out what you are actually doing here, let alone why it is leaking memory.  From what I have been able to deduce, you can call Java from MatLab, and you can call C++ directly from Matlab.  I cannot figure out if you are calling the C++ library directly, or calling it via a Java (JNI / JNA) wrapper.  And if you are doing the latter ... why.

For the Matlab -> C++ case, this page has some tips on avoiding memory leaks: http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/matlab_external/memory-management-issues.html

For the Matlab -> Java -> C++ case, the leaks could be due to bugs in the Java wrapper or its associated C++-side wrapper code, or a problem in the way that you are using the wrapper.  For instance, there could be some `dispose` method that you need to call.  The details should be in the Java API docs ... which you have not been able to locate ... or in the Java source code itself.

---

> I was hoping that there were some general memory clearing Java commands I could use.

There are no such magic commands.  You need to figure out where the memory is leaking and fix that.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I'm calling C++ via a Java wrapper with Matlab. I will try to dig in deeper and find out why the memory leak is occurring in the rraTool.run(); command. I'll take a look at the suggestions you provided. Thanks again!

Comment: It would be great to get code examples here. I am having a similar problem here http://askubuntu.com/q/799834/25388 but my matrices are so big that I am not convinced that this proposal can be sufficient.